# Installation of TensorFlow not found in Rstudio (on Mac)

Tags: r

I am new to TensorFlow and Keras and I installed them in Rstudio using a conda virtual environment. I run the following line and everything works.

```
library(reticulate)

use_condaenv("r-reticulate")

library(tensorflow)

library(keras)
```

However when I try to call the function "keras_model_sequential()" I get this error:

```
**Error: Python module tensorflow.keras was not found.

Detected Python configuration:

python:         /anaconda3/envs/r-reticulate/bin/python
libpython:      //anaconda3/envs/r-reticulate/lib/libpython3.6m.dylib
pythonhome:     /anaconda3/envs/r-reticulate:/anaconda3/envs/r-reticulate
version:        3.6.10 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 25 2020, 18:53:43)  [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)]
numpy:          /anaconda3/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.19.2
tensorflow:     /anaconda3/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow

python versions found: 
 /anaconda3/envs/r-reticulate/bin/python
 /usr/bin/python
 /anaconda3/envs/covid19/bin/python
 /anaconda3/envs/test/bin/python
 /anaconda3/envs/test2/bin/python
**
```

What should I do?  I am using a Mac with El Capitan (version 10.11.6). Thank you very much Riccardo